# Mysql version 5.6 jar version 5.1

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jar, version, wildfly

I have current MySQL version 5.6.22 x64 installed.
Can I user a v5.1 connector jar?
- Im not finding the 5.6 connector jar. Is there any?

The purpose is to configure my Wildfly server with it.

My OS is a Windows 8.1 x64bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. Connector/J 5.1.34 is latest version the official JDBC driver for MySQL.

See docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html

> Connector/J 5.1 is a Type 4 pure Java JDBC driver, which conforms to
>   the JDBC 3.0 and JDBC 4.0 specifications. It provides compatibility
>   with all the functionality of MySQL, including 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 5.5,
>   5.6, and 5.7.